# Dynamic 'Order' column based on 'Datetime_submitted' is not updating when 'Datetime_submitted' is updated

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating a queue management system where patrons can sign-up in person for passport applications and the staff are able to see a queue of people based off of their form submission time.
The code in my model.py is working for every scenario I have tried (New submissions, no-shows, cancelled, etc) except for if a staff were to change the form submission time to alter the order. When this occurs, the order number changes for the row modified but not any other rows. However, all I need to do to update the order on the rest of the rows is open up a row and click 'save' then all of the rows update.

This is a very minor issue and I could simply disallow the modification of the 'datetime_submitted' feild. However, this is my first Django project so I would love to know why the 'order' column doesn't update when the 'datetime_submitted' is modified.
Apologies in advance as this is also my first time asking a question as well.

I am just including my model.py file because the forms and stuff do not matter and all editing and testing is currently being done through the Django admin login.

**model.py**

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

from random import choices
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
import django
from django.db.models import Q
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

# Create your models here.

class Patron(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    photo_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    photo_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    minor_passport_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    adult_passport_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    expidited_passport_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total_passports = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    datetime_submitted = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
    datetime_started = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    datetime_finished = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    agent = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, related_name="patron", default=1)
    status = models.TextField(
        choices = (
            ("waiting","Waiting"),
            ("in_progress","In Progress"),
            ("executed","Executed"),
            ("cancelled","Cancelled"),
            ("coming_back","Coming Back"),
        ),
    )
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=1)


    @property
    def getActive(self):
        if self.status == "executed" or self.status == "cancelled":
            return False
        else:
            return True

    @property
    def getOrder(self):
        active = Patron.objects.filter(active=True).filter(~Q(id=self.id)).order_by('datetime_submitted')
        curOrder = 1
        nextOrder = 1
        if curOrder != -1:
            for i in active:
                #if it's added and it's time is greater than i's time add one to it's order number
                if i.datetime_submitted < self.datetime_submitted:
                    curOrder = curOrder + 1
                    nextOrder = nextOrder + 1
                #if it's added and it's time is less than i's time add on to the next order variable and assign it
                elif i.datetime_submitted > self.datetime_submitted and i.order > 0 and self.getActive and i.active:
                    nextOrder = nextOrder + 1
                    Patron.objects.filter(id=i.id).update(order = nextOrder)
                #if it's removed and it's time is less than i's sub one to the next order and assign
                elif i.datetime_submitted > self.datetime_submitted and self.getActive == False:
                    Patron.objects.filter(id=i.id).update(order = nextOrder)
                    nextOrder = nextOrder + 1
            if not self.getActive:
                curOrder = -1
        if curOrder == -1 and self.getActive:
            self.order = 0
            curOrder = self.getOrder
        return curOrder

        
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.active = self.getActive
        self.order = self.getOrder
        super(Patron, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Meta():
    ordering = ['-order','date_submitted']

                self._loaded_values['datetime_submitted'] = self.datetime_submitted
                self.save
                
        super(Patron, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Meta():
    ordering = ['-order','date_submitted']

#Creating the update form
```

**Solved**

Found this issue and it was super simple. Posting the whole code in case someone else could use it.

```py
   # -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

from random import choices
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
import django
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget

# Create your models here.

class Patron(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=200)
    photo_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    photo_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    minor_passport_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    adult_passport_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    expidited_passport_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total_passports = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    datetime_submitted = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
    datetime_started = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    datetime_finished = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    agent = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, related_name="patron", default=1)
    status = models.TextField(
        choices = (
            ("waiting","Waiting"),
            ("in_progress","In Progress"),
            ("executed","Executed"),
            ("cancelled","Cancelled"),
            ("coming_back","Coming Back"),
        ),
    )
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    @classmethod
    def from_db(cls, db, field_names, values):

        instance = super().from_db(db, field_names, values)
        instance._loaded_values = dict(zip(field_names,values))
        return instance

    @property
    def getActive(self):
        if self.status == "executed" or self.status == "cancelled":
            return False
        else:
            return True

    @property
    def getOrder(self):
        active = Patron.objects.filter(active=True).filter(~Q(id=self.id)).order_by('datetime_submitted')
        curOrder = 1
        nextOrder = 1
        
        for i in active:
            #if it's added and it's time is greater than i's time add one to it's order number
            if i.datetime_submitted < self.datetime_submitted:
                curOrder = curOrder + 1
                Patron.objects.filter(id=i.id).update(order = nextOrder)
                nextOrder = nextOrder + 1
            #if it's added and it's time is less than i's time add on to the next order variable and assign it
            elif i.datetime_submitted > self.datetime_submitted and i.order > 0 and self.getActive and i.active:
                nextOrder = nextOrder + 1
                Patron.objects.filter(id=i.id).update(order = nextOrder)
            #if it's removed and it's time is less than i's sub one to the next order and assign
            elif i.datetime_submitted > self.datetime_submitted and self.getActive == False:
                Patron.objects.filter(id=i.id).update(order = nextOrder)
                nextOrder = nextOrder + 1
        #This is here just in case I missed something or a photon flips a bit.
        if not self.getActive:
            curOrder = -1
        if curOrder == -1 and self.getActive:
            self.order = 0
            curOrder = self.getOrder
        return curOrder

        
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.active = self.getActive
        self.order = self.getOrder
        if not self._state.adding:
            newDate = self.datetime_submitted
            if self._loaded_values['datetime_submitted'] != self.datetime_submitted and self._loaded_values['datetime_submitted'] != None:
                self._loaded_values['datetime_submitted'] = self.datetime_submitted
                self.save
                
        super(Patron, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Meta():
    ordering = ['-order','date_submitted']

#Creating the update form
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer just in case anyone was curious or it helps so poor chap in the future.

```
for i in active:
        #if it's added and it's time is greater than i's time add one to it's order number
        if i.datetime_submitted < self.datetime_submitted:
            curOrder = curOrder + 1
            #THIS LINE BELOW IS ALL I ADDED.....
            Patron.objects.filter(id=i.id).update(order = nextOrder)
            nextOrder = nextOrder + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a DB call within a forloop will probably create waaay more queries than you want. Furthermore, you are doing `Patron.objects.filter(id=i.id).update(...)` in the `i` loop, but `.update()` can be used on a number of objects inside a queryset. If you combine `.update()` with an `F()` object then you can update each field without having to loop through each object.

There seems to be some complicated sorting process in your for loop which I haven't fully understood. I think you should simply filter for the objects that exist before the current one's date, these can stay the same. Take the most recent of those and add 1 to the order number - this becomes our new order number for the current object. For all objects that exist after this one, we want to use `F()` to update the order number and add 1 to each.

```py
def getOrder(self):
    # get the Patron object immediately before this one
    last_active = Patron.objects.filter(
        active=True,
        datetime_submitted__lt=self.datetime_submitted
    ).order_by('-datetime_submitted').first()
    
    # update the current Patron's order number based on this one
    self.order = last_active.order + 1
    self.save()

    # filter all Patrons after this one and add 1 to it's order number
    Patron.objects.filter(
        active=True,
        datetime_submitted__gte=self.datetime_submitted
    ).exclude(
        id=self.id
    ).update(order=F('order')+1)
```